# The value in the map taken by SprinEL is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

what I want to ask is that in the process of using springel, I want to get the value in the map, but no matter how I get it, my value will always be null

```
@Data
@Component("workersHolder")
public class WorkersHolder {
    private Map<String, Integer> salaryByWorkers = new HashMap<>();

    public WorkersHolder() {

        salaryByWorkers.put("John", 35000);
        salaryByWorkers.put("Susie", 47000);
        salaryByWorkers.put("Alex", 12000);
        salaryByWorkers.put("George", 14000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 35000
        System.out.println(new WorkersHolder().salaryByWorkers.get("John"));
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@Component
public class GetData {

    @Value("#{workersHolder.salaryByWorkers['John']}")
    private Integer johnSalary;

    @Value("#{workersHolder.salaryByWorkers['George']}")
    private Integer georgeSalary;

    @Value("#{workersHolder.salaryByWorkers['Susie']}")
    private Integer susieSalary;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // null
        // Hope this line can output 35000
       System.out.println(new GetData().johnSalary);
    }
}
```

The line in bold prints 35000 as expected, but is null
May I ask if there is a step I did wrong, any ideas are welcome to provide to me, thank you

Comment: `GetData.main` is not managed by spring... but values should be set when you start your spring-boot app.

Comment: Furthermore, to access it from SpEL, the field has to be public, or a public getter must be present; SpEL will coerce `salaryByWorkers` to `getSalaryByWorkers()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `@Test` instead of   `public static void main(String[] args)` for unit test ,and
The   `GetData` which in your code snap  is not in `spring ioc`, spring can not manage it , therefore , `spring el` is invaild;

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GetDataTest{
    @Autowired
    private GetData getData;
    @Test
    public void test(){
        Assert.notNull(getData,"getData not be null");
        System.out.println(getData);

    }
}
```

if you bulid project with `maven` , you should add `junit` or `spring-test` dependency , it is recommanded to add `spring-test` below

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version> // your spring version 
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```